# How to import node module into a custom script in react public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my React project, I must create a script in the public folder,
But when I try to import a node module in this script:

```
import someVariable from '@module/someVariable';
```

I'm having this error:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Use `require` instead of `import`, if you are using a script outside a module. For example: `const {someVariable} = require('@module/someVariable');`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that doesn't work, I'm getting this error : ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Seems like it is not installed in your node env. If you are using NPM, install it using `npm install requirejs`. For other installations, see [docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html)

Comment: I have already did that, but I'm always having the error ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: You are running this on node? Try to execute it as `node --experimental-modules script.js`. Otherwise, check your package.json file for the type property. If that is set to module, remove it, so you can use require. But you can use either require or import in a single npm project.

Comment: I did all that, but it doesn't work I can't use neither the import or the require

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250228/discussion-between-jishan-shaikh-and-oussama-eddahri).